# Force numpy to use OpenBlas

Tags: python, numpy, openblas

Basically, I need to multiply two arrays of (10^6 x 10^6) integer elements and I couldn't get to work with numpy.dot.
Checking on other posts I saw that if I switched the type of my matrix to float32 or bigger, if I had openblas installed which I have, the dot operation will be faster.
I actually changed my array tipe to float32 and it actually went much much faster.

So my question is, assuming numpy is really using OpenBlas, is there any way to force numpy use the OpenBlas library so I could still have my matrix as an int type?

Here I let you my numpy config if it's of any help.

```
np.__config__.show()
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
```

Comment: I don't think OpenBlas has integer-support. The [branch](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/tree/integer_datatype) seems not to be merged and quite experimental. While Intel's MKL seems to have that feature, i'm sceptical about numpy's ability to use it (as there will be a more complex backend-mechanism depending on which BLAS is available).

Comment: Thank you! I understand then that I should continue working as I'm now? Using numpy.dot and defining the arrays as float32?